# returning invaild data with Regular Expression in Vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

Following is MY code

```
  Dim ReadTagdata As String = "Info,Reply:Axis 0, Channel G, Timestamp 2eff, SpecificID f00ba36d, CRC d01ed74e, ReadAddress 000a, Data: 7a7a 3433 3132 3334 3536 3738 3637 2c31 352c 302e 3036 2c2e 3930 2d31 2e32 322c 526f 756e 642c 462c 5653 322c 7665 7279 2067 6f6f 642c 676f 6f64 2c76 6572 7920 676f 6f64 2c6d 6564 6975 6d2c 4852 442c 3137 3530 3234 3837 3333 2c32 352d 4175 672d 3130 2c33 2e39 342c 332e 3932 2c32 2e38 322c 332e 3839 2c35 362c 3131 2e35 2c34 332c 6d65 6469 756d 2c70 6f69 6e74 6564 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 4e2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c"

    Dim Specificcol As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(ReadTagdata, "SpecificID ([a-f0-9]{8})")
    For Each m As Match In Specificcol
        Dim g As Group = m.Groups(1)
        MsgBox(g.Value.ToString)
    Next


    Dim DataCol As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(ReadTagdata, "Data: ([A-Za-z0-9\-]+) ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    For Each mdata As Match In DataCol
        Dim gdata As Group = mdata.Groups(1)
        Dim data As String = gdata.Value.ToString
        MsgBox(data)
    Next
```

In above code i trying to retrieve, require data from ReadTagData string with a regular
expression
but with the following code, i can able to retrive only 1 value after **Data:** string i.e. **7a7a,**
instead of that, i want the all strings after the **"DATA:"** string

**Dim DataCol As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(ReadTagdata, "Data: ([A-Za-z0-9-]+) ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This Regular expression:

```
Data:\s([\w\s\-])+
```

Matches this:

```
Data: 7a7a 3433 3132 3334 3536 3738 3637 2c31 352c 302e 3036 2c2e 3930 2d31 2e32 322c 526f 756e 6-42c 462c 5653 322c 7665 7279 2067 6f6f 642c 676f 6f64 2c76 6572 7920 676f 6f64 2c6d 6564 6975 6d2c 4852 442c 3137 3530 3234 3837 3333 2c32 352d 4175 672d 3130 2c33 2e39 342c 332e 3932 2c32 2e38 322c 332e 3839 2c35 362c 3131 2e35 2c34 332c 6d65 6469 756d 2c70 6f69 6e74 6564 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 4e2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c
```

And the `Group` 1 of this Regular expression:

```
Data:\s([\w\s\-]+)
```

Matches this:

```
7a7a 3433 3132 3334 3536 3738 3637 2c31 352c 302e 3036 2c2e 3930 2d31 2e32 322c 526f 756e 6-42c 462c 5653 322c 7665 7279 2067 6f6f 642c 676f 6f64 2c76 6572 7920 676f 6f64 2c6d 6564 6975 6d2c 4852 442c 3137 3530 3234 3837 3333 2c32 352d 4175 672d 3130 2c33 2e39 342c 332e 3932 2c32 2e38 322c 332e 3839 2c35 362c 3131 2e35 2c34 332c 6d65 6469 756d 2c70 6f69 6e74 6564 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 4e2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c
```

---

Notes:

> \w = Alphanumeric characters plus "_"
>
> \s = Space characters
>
> \- = "-" character

---

For testing more Regular expressions in the futre I will recommend you a simple RegEx tester application that I've developed time ago, this is the way how I managed to do these expressions that you needed:

[image]

[image]

Download source code here: http://elektrostudios.tk/RegEx.NET.zip

Comment: Thanx for help,but  Dim DataCol As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(ReadTagdata, "Data:\s([\w\s\-])+"), i will get only one charater that "c"

Comment: You need to use this regex `Data:\s([\w\s\-]+)` and the Matches group `1` as I said.  `Dim DataCol As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(ReadTagdata, "Data:\s([\w\s\-]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Comment: Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(ReadTagdata, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

        For Each match As Match In matches
            MsgBox(match.Groups(1).Value)
        Next